# tenho problema ao subir meu site no github pages

Tags: css, imagem, upload, github

simplesmente, todos os arquivos que estão nas pasta nao carregam, fotos, css externos e js externos. A unica coisa que carrega são os arquivos css e js internos. verifiquei o caminho e ta tudo certo. Alguém me ajuda pfv!!
https://github.com/Apolinar1o/Apolinar1oDeveloper-s
https://apolinar1o.github.io/Apolinar1oDeveloper-s/

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Comment: colocou caminho relativo ao repositorio  a plataforma não reconhece esse caminho. Tera que reeditar o caminho e coloca-lo de forma completa.

Comment: Ao indicar o caminho **_javascript/funcoes.js** não ocorrera a aplicação do estilo na pagina. simplesmente pq não é diretório como no computador. github possui repositórios que podem ser visíveis pelo caminho completo pela url.. que pode ser acessado navegando dentro do diretorio e no canto superior ao lado de Blame.. onde esta escrito "raw"  ao ser clicado aparecera na url o caminho correto a ser indicado na paginas html.

Comment: abri um **pull request** para que possa ver como é que o gihub reconhece o que esta sendo referenciado.

Answer (score -3):

Dei uma olhada em seu repositório. O que está te causando dor de cabeça é somente a nomeclatura das pastas que você está utilizando. O simples fato de você remover o `_` do inicio, por exemplo do CSS como mostrado na imagem abaixo, e importar conforme a alteração já fará funcionar corretamente.

[image: Print do espaço de trabalho com as alterações sugeridas acima.]

Outra coisa é tentar ser um pouco mais específico para o caminho dos arquivos, mesmo que sejam relativos.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: O problema dele está bem claro, ao subir o seu projeto para o github pages a importação dos assets dele não está funcionando corretamente. Ao investigar, pelo repositório ao qual ele disponibilizou o link, identifiquei que o problema está apenas na forma que ele nomeia suas pastas. Não consegui compreender o que fez com que a pergunta dele não ficasse clara e nem o motivo da minha resposta não ser boa o bastante.